# Is it possible to plug two USB-C devices into one USB-C port?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, usb-c

I have a two year old HP Spectre laptop. It has one USB-C port, which besides used for other USB-C devices, it is also used to rechage my laptop. That USB-C port is the only way of charging the laptop.

Recently I got a second monitor that I can use with my laptop. It also plugs into my laptop through the USB-C port. I thought, "I've got such a port on my laptop, I'm good to go", then thought nothing more about it, until now. I needed to recharge my laptop and wanted to connect my new secondary monitor to it when I suddenly realized I can't plug them both into the same port.

Duh. My fault for not thinking this through better.

So, is it possible for me to get some sort of adapter or hub type of thing, to plug into my USB-C port on my laptop, then connect two (at least) other USB-C devices into it? Especially if one of those secondary devices is the charging cable to recharge my laptop?

Comment: See https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/charging-via-usb-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is it possible for me to get some sort of adapter or hub type of thing, to plug into my USB-C port on my laptop, then connect two (at least) other USB-C devices into it? Especially if one of those secondary devices is the charging cable to recharge my laptop?

Only if the adapter, dock, or hub is Thunderbolt, USB4, or violates the USB specifications.

USB 3.x didn't define how a USB-C hub was supposed to work.  That's why you will find plenty of docks with all kinds of ports on them, and if they have a USB-C port then it will be for power only.  If there is a second USB-C port (and this might violate the spec just by having more than one USB-C port) then it will only support USB 3.x devices.

Even though the people behind USB didn't define how a USB-C hub is supposed to work there may be a way to make USB-C hubs that meet the spec.  Given that none exist, that I could find anyway, my guess is that the USB people will not give their approval to any USB-C hubs.

The USB-C spec will allow for USB-C ports to have, as an example, only DisplayPort on it.  The same goes for power only USB-C (defined in the USB-PD spec), USB 2.0 only USB-C, USB 3.x only USB-C, and so on.  To make a compliant hub then would likely then mean labeling every port with the protocol it supports.  A common multi-port USB-C dock might have two DisplayPort outputs, 6 USB-A ports, a USB-C power in port, audio input, audio output, and Ethernet.  Because USB-C has alternate modes that cover all of those protocols except Ethernet it is possible to build a dock that can do the same stuff and connect the same devices with one Ethernet port and the rest, all 8 or 9 of them, are USB-C.

There's two big reasons not to make a USB-C dock like this.  One is that there isn't going to be a lot of demand.  Another is that this will no doubt create all kinds of support calls on how the (no doubt clearly differently labelled) ports are not the same.  It may be impossible to make all of them the same because how to make them act in a predictable manner is not defined in the USB specs.

This doesn't apply to Thunderbolt, there are Thunderbolt docks and hubs on the market and they will have multiple USB-C ports.  These will not likely work that well for a host computer that does not support Thunderbolt.  USB4 does appear to define how a USB-C hub should work.  How well this works, or if it works at all, with USB 3.x has yet to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a dock.

If money is no issue, this should work for you.  If it is, then check the site for something a little less expensive.

[USB-C Dock - 4K Triple Monitor Laptop Docking Station with Dual DisplayPort & HDMI - 100W Power Delivery](https://www.startech.com/en-ca/cards-adapters/dk30ch2dep)

Comment: You can solve this for a fraction of that price - https://www.amazon.com/Anker-PowerExpand-Adapter-Delivery-Ethernet/dp/B087QZVQJX

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, I have just ordered one on eBay for £3.50.

Dual 2 in 1 Type C to USB-C Headphone Audio Charger Adapter Splitter Converter.

[https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/~DEAAOSw-11fpWn-/s-l300.jpg](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/%7EDEAAOSw-11fpWn-/s-l300.jpg)